# Angular resolve Rxjs map and subscribe multiple APIs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

Application need to fetch the jwt token first and then using token, collect portal information. This code is written in resolver.

This code make an error exception :

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

When `Observable<any>` is removed, resolve data is not available in component and it initiates components before resolve completes

```
@Injectable()
export class PortalLoadingResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
      private authService:AuthService,
      private emiDataService:EmiDataService,
    ) { }

    resolve():Observable<any> {
      return this.authService.getJwtToken()
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(JwtToken => {
        debugger;
        localStorage.setItem('id_token',JwtToken.token);
        return this.emiDataService.getBasicLoadingDatas();
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method isn't returning `Observable` here, that is what Typescript is yelling. Because once you applied subscribe method over `Observable` it return `Subscription` of observable. You could easily return a `Observable` by chaining Observable with `switchMap` operator.

```
resolve():Observable<any> {
  return this.authService.getJwtToken()
  .map(res => res.json())
  .switchMap(JwtToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token',JwtToken.token);
    return this.emiDataService.getBasicLoadingDatas();
  });
}
```